# A word for one who perseveres?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a noun to describe a person who perseveres? I suppose a *survivor* is one who has survived difficult circumstances, and a *soldier* could be one that soldiers on, but neither word has quite the right connotation. I want the sense of "continue in a course of action even in the face of difficulty" without necessarily calling to mind images of trauma or war.

Comment: What did you find when you looked up synonyms of *persevere*, so that we don't give you words you don't want? Also, do you want a noun or an adjective, as adjectives *describe*.

Comment: I didn't find any words with an associated "one who <verb>s" noun other than the ones that I listed. And actually, I didn't even find those in the thesaurus I was using.

Comment: I'm looking for a *noun*, as stated in the question

Comment: I like _perseverer,_ or if that's not enough, _perseverationist._

Comment: @JohnLawler Your ***perseverer*** seems best when sticking to the basic word. It does remind me of something that gets ***severed*** (as with Gene Wolfe’s headsman, who’s named *Severian*), but then so too does Shakespeare’s spelling of the verb *persever* without a final *e* as we use today. Pity that *perseverant* is almost only ever used adjectivally. Apparently *perseverate* has its own special meaning to the shrinks, so I don’t know that *perseverationist* would work for all audiences.  However, if it did, then one might as well shorten it down to ***perseverator***.

Comment: @Joe Someone who continues in a course of action even in the face of difficulty such as hardship, conflict, illness, etc., is someone that fights; hence a fighter ("battant" in French).

Comment: @tchrist: I gave it as an answer already before comments. Though it does not seem like a common word.

Comment: A _survivor_ is not only one who _has survived_ but also one who is surviving. It is often used to indicate someone who perseveres, who does not quit, who is hard to put down. Why is that not a good fit for you?

Comment: @terdon One can survive out of good luck or against his/her will.

Comment: @Elian: ["a person who is able to continue living their life successfully despite experiencing difficulties"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/survivor). Also, google search for ["he's a survivor"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22he's%20a%20survivor%22). The term is most certainly used in the meaning the OP seems to be asking for.

Comment: @terdon: But to be considered a survivor in the meaning you're referring to, one first needs to be a fighter. http://metro.co.uk/2014/01/22/hes-a-fighter-schumachers-wife-clings-to-hope-as-it-emerges-f1-star-may-never-recover-from-ski-injury-4273636/

Comment: You might say such a person is a "diehard" (1. a person who vigorously maintains or defends a seemingly hopeless position, outdated attitude, lost cause, or the like.)

Answer (score 7):

I think the best slang term I can think of is [trooper](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=trooper).

> Anyone who exhibits EXTREME perseverence, fortitude, and tenacity.

**Usage:**

- Bill has had cancer 4 times and is still in great shape, he's such a trooper.

Note: As Gnawme indicated in the comments [trouper](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trouper?show=0&t=1400019341) is an alternative spelling.

---

I also offer *stoic*, as it is someone who perseveres and does so without complaining.

> noun noun: stoic; plural noun: stoics; noun: Stoic; plural noun:
>   Stoics
>
> 1. a person who can endure pain or hardship without showing their feelings or complaining.

---

And since I cannot resist on using sports terms for everything.  If this person were playing football, soccer, baseball, basketball, and they went through a lot of hardships and injuries yet still played on through everything they might be called a *gamer*.

**Usage:** Bob has a pulled hamstring and a beat up foot but he has played the last 3 days, he such a gamer.

Comment: Actually, the term is [_trouper_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trouper?show=0&t=1400019341).

Comment: Thanks @Gnawme!  I had no idea there was an alternative spelling to it.  I have used trooper my entire life - maybe it is AE?  I will edit to add that in.

Comment: Well, [_trooper_](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trooper?s=t) is an _incorrect_ spelling of _trouper_; see the "Can be confused" note at the link.

Comment: @Gnawme - The OED gives these definitions of the colloquial uses:

trooper: A brave or stalwart person.
trouper: A reliable, uncomplaining person; a staunch supporter or colleague.  I have a feeling it was a common misspelling that became eventually acceptable.

Comment: trooper and trouper are different words with different etymologies and meanings. The primary associations for trooper all have to do with military troops, which is why the colloquial version focuses on bravery.

Comment: @Joe - Americans spell with 'oo' and barely 'ou'.  As mentioned I know what a state trooper is but most Americans would spell this trooper.  And if you spelled it trouper they might be thrown off on the meaning.

Answer (score 5):

***[undeterred](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/undeterred)***

> Persevering with something despite setbacks
>
> *he was undeterred by these disasters*

You can check the [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/undeterred) also. I would also add that adjectives are better for this context.

---

Apparently, **[*perseverer*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perseverer)** is a word and a noun, though it is not that common.

> one that perseveres :  a persistent person

From the book "The Great Awakening: A Buddhist Social Theory" *By David Loy*:

> Each Tibetan knew that the moral Buddhist cared more for the welfare of others more than his or her own welfare, gave others rather than amassed a fortune, rigorously tried to prevent harm to others, never engaged in any of the nonvirtuous acts, had complete devotion to the Buddha and his path, worked to eliminate anger and desire for material goods, accepted problems with patience and endurance, and remained an enthusiastic ***perseverer*** in the quest for truth and enlightenment.

---

Also ***[endurer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Endurer)*** as a noun:

> One who, or that which, endures or lasts; one who bears, suffers, or sustains.

From "Don Quixote" *by Cervantes, Miguel*:

> Humble with the proud, haughty with the humble, encounterer of dangers, ***endurer*** of outrages, enamoured without reason, imitator of the good, scourge of the wicked, enemy of the mean, in short, knight-errant, which is all that can be said!

Comment: Perseverer is technically the word I'm looking for, but it just sounds so *awkward*; it doesn't sound like a real word.

Comment: @Joe: Yes it is not a common word as I mentioned. In my opinion, adjectives are better for this context.

Comment: Do you have any example usages of either noun?

Comment: @Joe: Added example usages. It is a bit challenge to find examples also because you come up with French sources when you search them.

Comment: perseverer isn't in the oed, although endurer is. I don't know how you found any examples of usage of perseverer. I couldn't.

Comment: Not all words are in OED.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [**fighter**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fighter).

> [**fighter**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fighter): a pugnacious, unyielding, or determined person; a person with the courage or determination to fight, struggle, etc.
>
> "*They say he's stable, he's gained a little weight, and his lungs are in better shape. "He's a [**fighter**](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=JinIy94fhA8C&pg=PA444&lpg=PA444&dq=%22shape+he%27s+a+fighter%22&source=bl&ots=sEkH9jAtm3&sig=E1OLnbtFz62kvzB3BrgnjBJ7SRg&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=V_hyU6qtMMeo0QWVroCACQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22shape%20he%27s%20a%20fighter%22&f=false)," she said*."
>
> "*[**I'm A Fighter**](http://imafighter.org/tag/lyme-disease/)*"

On different levels, someone who continues in a course of action even in the face of difficulty can be described as a [**go-getter**](http://www.gogetterbooks.com/listing-you-don-t-have-to-quit-how-to-persevere-when-you-want-to-give-up.php), a [**winner**](http://www.delawarepolitics.net/hillary-in-biden-out-in-2012/), or a [**diehard**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/die-hard).

Answer (score 2):

[Obdurate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obdurate)

Stubbornly refusing to change one’s opinion or course of action:

> I argued this point with him, but he was obdurate

You might also refer to a mountain as 'obdurate' as it exists essentially unchanged regardless of weather and humanity. So further to its innate meaning, similes like, 'he is obdurate as the mountain' can be constructed in the semantic direction you seek.

**edit:** didn't see that you wanted a noun specifically, so:

[Adamant/Adamance/Adamancy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adamant) Stemming from *adamas* latin for invincible, untameable.

> Refusing to be persuaded or to change one’s mind

Comment: Via Latin, but _άδαμας_ itself is Greek. (Sorry for the missing _spiritus lenis_; typing on my phone.)

Answer (score 2):

A *noun* which does not contain any connotations of war or trauma as requested by the OP is a *[nonquitter](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonquitter)* also spelled *non-quitter*

- One who is not a quitter.

[image]

[Source](http://books.google.it/books?id=LsKxs8hVmUoC&pg=PA111&dq=%22a%20non%20quitter%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=16ZyU9u_J6Od7gawi4GIBQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20non%20quitter%22&f=false)

Comment: @Mari-LouA the old comments are stale after the edit. Removing.

Answer (score 1):

[*determined*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/determined): strongly motivated to succeed (undismayed, undaunted, single-minded).

John Kerry tells Israeli TV he will get the Israeli-Palestinian peace deal done. *He is determined.*

For *nouns*, there are *warrior*, *hero*, and *champion*.

Answer (score 1):

*Battler*. In northern English you might say 'he's a battler' meaning someone who has struggled against large odds.

Answer (score 1):

A perseverant person/endeavour/effort.

> [per·se·ver·ant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perseverant) adjective -nt\
>   able or willing to persevere :  enduring 
>   Origin of PERSEVERANT
>   *Middle English perseveraunt, from Middle French perseverant, from Latin perseverant-, perseverans, present participle of perseverare*

Comment: The question requested a noun; I can find no substantive uses of *perseverant* to speak of.

Comment: With much appreciation for the determined and obdurate reminder.

Comment: I cannot speak for others, but I would fully understand *perseverant* were it used substantively.  This seems to be the most eloquent recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Someone with stick-to-itiveness is called a *sticker*. 
From the OED:

> **Sticker** 3a.) One who or something which adheres or remains attached; one who remains constant; one who persists in a task. Const. to, †unto.

and two examples of usage, also from the OED:

1967   ‘C. Fremlin’ Prisoner's Base xii. 84   Daphne did not believe in dropping things; she was, as she would have told you, a Sticker.

1979   N. Hynd False Flags viii. 71   Bobby wasn't any quitter. He was a sticker.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is Stoic.

Comment: Welcome to ELU :-)! Stoic is a fitting word for the OP's question (IMO), but your answer would substantially improve if you added a definition or examples of usage, with references. This way it would be more useful for both the OP and future users of the website. You can always edit your own posts, regardless of your current reputation.